# Using Imagemagick to add 2 text strings with drop shadow to a background

Tags: imagemagick

I am trying to place 2 annotated texts onto a background in different locations and give the text font shadow. A single text works fine, but when I add the second, it blurs the background and the rest of the image.

Here is the image results: https://i.stack.imgur.com/27zeB.jpg

The first command works as expected:

```
convert ~/.backgrounds/White.jpg -font Bitter -pointsize 72 -annotate +130+170 'Anthony' -blur 0x4 -fill white  -annotate +125+165 'Anthony' font_shadow_fuzzy.jpg
```

The second messes everything up and I need to know how I fix it.

```
convert ~/.backgrounds/White.jpg -font Bitter -pointsize 72 -annotate +130+170 'Anthony' -blur 0x4 -fill white  -annotate +125+165 'Anthony'  -annotate +230+270 'Anthony' -blur 0x4 -fill white  -annotate +225+265 'Anthony' font_shadow_fuzzy.jpg
```

Comment: You can use `caption` to make it. Refer to [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57309466/6521116)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are having with your Imagemagick command is that **the second -blur affects the first text**. So you need to separate the processing for each text and put it on a transparent background. Then flatten the two results onto a white background.

The following works for me with Imagemagick 6.9.10.9 Q16 Mac OSX Sierra:

```
convert \
\( -size 600x400 xc:none -font ubuntu -pointsize 72 -fill black -annotate +130+170 'Anthony' -blur 0x4 -fill white  -annotate +125+165 'Anthony' \) \
\( -size 600x400 xc:none -font ubuntu -pointsize 72 -fill black -annotate +230+270 'Anthony' -blur 0x4 -fill white  -annotate +225+265 'Anthony' \) \
-background white -flatten \
font_shadow_fuzzy.jpg
```

Uploading does not seem to be working at this time, so here is a link to the result:

http://www.fmwconcepts.com/misc_tests/font_shadow_fuzzy.jpg

You did not say how big your white background image was. So if I assume it is 600x400, then I will create one and modify the command. You could use any other background, but need to know how big it is for the transparent background to your text.

```
convert -size 600x400 xc:white white.jpg

convert white.jpg \
\( -size 600x400 xc:none -font ubuntu -pointsize 72 -fill black -annotate +130+170 'Anthony' -blur 0x4 -fill white  -annotate +125+165 'Anthony' \) \
\( -size 600x400 xc:none -font ubuntu -pointsize 72 -fill black -annotate +230+270 'Anthony' -blur 0x4 -fill white  -annotate +225+265 'Anthony' \) \
-flatten \
font_shadow_fuzzy2.jpg
```

Or, for any arbitrary background that is larger than where you  want to place your text, you can find the dimensions and do the processing as follows:

```
infile="white.jpg"
dim=`convert "$infile" -format "%wx%h" info:`
convert "$infile" \
\( -size $dim xc:none -font ubuntu -pointsize 72 -fill black -annotate +130+170 'Anthony' -blur 0x4 -fill white  -annotate +125+165 'Anthony' \) \
\( -size $dim xc:none -font ubuntu -pointsize 72 -fill black -annotate +230+270 'Anthony' -blur 0x4 -fill white  -annotate +225+265 'Anthony' \) \
-flatten \
font_shadow_fuzzy3.jpg
```

One other way to do this is to make two small text images with your shadow as separate images on a white background. The black blurred text would have and offset of +5+5 and the white unblurred text would have offsets of +0+0. Do this for both images, then composite them onto your background white image at the desired offsets using -geometry for the offsets.